# Can I programmatically generate a list of local pure ESM node_modules for Webpack/babel-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, babel-loader, serverless-webpack-plugin

Is there an easy way to get a list of your local `node_modules` that are pure ESM (i.e. only support ES6 import/export syntax)?

While trying to create a CommonJS bundle for a Serverless Framework project I needed to use npm packages that had recently gone pure ESM. This meant manually listing them in my Webpack config.

The solution to using pure ESM modules (details in [this blog post](https://dev.to/joostschuur/using-pure-esm-npm-packages-in-serverless-webpack-bundles-apd)) that I came up with was to first tweak the babel-loader exclude definition so that any modules I know to be pure ESM (and its pure ESM dependencies) are still transpiled then also make sure that webpack-node-externals passed these transpiled versions into the bundle by defining them in the `allowlist`.

Now I'd like to automate getting that list of third-party pure ESM modules in my project (along with their dependencies), so I don't have to keep maintaining it by hand.

Maybe loop through everything in `package-lock.json` as a starting point?

Here's what that currently looks like ([sample repo](https://github.com/jschuur/serverless-prisma-esm)). `pureESMModules` is the list I'd like to programmatically generate:

```js
const path = require('path');

const babelLoaderExcludeNodeModulesExcept = require('babel-loader-exclude-node-modules-except');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');

const { isLocal } = slsw.lib.webpack;

const pureESMModules = ['pretty-ms', 'parse-ms'];

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  stats: 'normal',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  externals: [nodeExternals({ allowlist: pureESMModules })],
  mode: isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: { concatenateModules: false },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: babelLoaderExcludeNodeModulesExcept(pureESMModules),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
  },
};
```

I use serverless-webpack and set [`includeModules`](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#node-modules--externals) to `true` to specifically tell it to bundle modules, which then applies to the transpiled versions that babel-loader generated:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules: true
```

Have I actually over-engineered this? It does feel like something Webpack should have already been doing for me. Or are there valid reasons it (or webpack-node-externals) can't programmatically identify which pure ESM modules to handle differently?

I know that excluding most modules in babel-loader is just there for performance reasons. If I skip that exclude option entirely, it would transpile everything and just run a little slower. I still need `pureESMModules` for my `allowlist` definition though.

**Edit**: Turns out [webpack-node-module-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-module-types) does get you a list of ESM modules, so in my example above, I use this now:

```js
const { determineModuleTypes } =
  require('webpack-node-module-types/sync');

// ...

const pureESMModules = determineModuleTypes()?.esm || [];
```

You might need to do something about filtering out the ESM modules that are only used by devDependencies, in case Webpack can't tree-kshake those, or you will end up with unnecessary code in your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [webpack-node-module-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-module-types) to get a list of ESM modules, and then also matching those up against just my dependencies, so I don't needlessly bundle up devDependencies:

```js
const path = require('path');

const babelLoaderExcludeNodeModulesExcept = require('babel-loader-exclude-node-modules-except');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const getPureESMDependencies = require('./util/pureESMDependencies.js');

const pureESMDependencies = getPureESMDependencies();

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  stats: 'normal',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  externals: [nodeExternals({ allowlist: pureESMDependencies.map((dep) => RegExp(`^${dep}(/.*)?$`)) })],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: { concatenateModules: false },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: babelLoaderExcludeNodeModulesExcept(pureESMDependencies),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
  },
};
```

Note how for the `allowlist`, I also use an array of regexps, which also catches some packages that imported stuff like `formdata-polyfill/esm.min.js`.

`pureESMDependencies.js` then looks like this:

```js
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const { determineModuleTypes } = require('webpack-node-module-types/sync');

// Recursively get all dependencies (not dev, peer) for the current project
function getDependencies(packageJsonLock, packages, knownDependencies = new Set()) {
  if (!packages?.length) return [];

  packages.forEach((packageName) => {
    const dependencies = Object.keys(packageJsonLock.packages[`node_modules/${packageName}`].dependencies || {});

    knownDependencies.add(packageName);
    if (dependencies.length) {
      dependencies.forEach((dependency) => knownDependencies.add(dependency));

      getDependencies(packageJsonLock, dependencies, knownDependencies);
    }
  });

  return [...knownDependencies];
}

// Get a list of packages that are pure ESM and in the 'dependencies' list in package.json
module.exports = function getPureESMDependencies() {
  const packageJsonLock = jsonfile.readFileSync('./package-lock.json');
  const packageJson = jsonfile.readFileSync('./package.json');

  const esmModules = determineModuleTypes()?.esm;
  if (!esmModules?.length) return [];

  const allDependencies = getDependencies(packageJsonLock, Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies));
  console.log({ allDependencies });

  return esmModules.filter((packageName) => allDependencies.includes(packageName));
};
```